# How do you compare 2-3 Datasets, record by record?

Tags: crm-analytics

I'm working in an org that has 100s of GBs of data. There are multiple data jobs that are creating/updating this data and it's difficult to determine the changes. Since CRM Analytics allows you to create copies of data with Datasets, is there a way to easily compare 2-3 Datasets at the same time? Or is there a way to see how a single Dataset has changed over time?

Comment: 100 GBs of data and a record-by-record comparison? Yeah, [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What do you think my X is? I know my data is being changed from multiple integrations. I know I want to see what is changing. I know I want to compare the changes over time.

Comment: _I know I want to see what is changing. I know I want to compare the changes over time_ - that's on the way to a problem statement but it isn't _the_ problem. You want to know what is changing and compare changes why?

Comment: To understand how two different data jobs are manipulating the data. There appears to be a data integrity problem.

Comment: I found some similar queries posted here - https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6njqSAB/comparing-two-datasets and https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C5iEfSAJ/compare-two-datasets-for-changes - not sure if those help.

Comment: _There appears to be a data integrity problem_ - still not a problem statement but close enough. If that's the X, the Y is implementing data integrity "rules". For 100 GB worth of data, this could mean schema-level changes or various automation techniques or modifying the sources of data